# How to style geojson polygon using L.mapbox.featureLayer()

Tags: javascript, mapbox, leaflet

I have this code:

```
    var SupIncend = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
    var ArbolesAntes = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
    var ArbolesX = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
    var ArbolesDespues = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

    L.control.layers({
        'Superficie incendiada': SupIncend.loadURL('http://www.mapatraslasierra.com.ar/ProyectoForestal/geojson/zona_incendio_unida.geojson')
    },{
        'Superficie arbolada Agosto 2013': ArbolesAntes.loadURL('http://www.mapatraslasierra.com.ar/ProyectoForestal/geojson/ArbolesPerennes_AntesIncendio.geojson'),
        'Superficie arbolada Octubre 2013': ArbolesX.loadURL('http://www.mapatraslasierra.com.ar/ProyectoForestal/geojson/ArbolesPerennes_Sobrevivantes.geojson'),
        'Superficie arbolada Julio 2014': ArbolesDespues.loadURL('http://www.mapatraslasierra.com.ar/ProyectoForestal/geojson/ArbolesPerennes_Rebrote.geojson')
        }).addTo(map);
```

It is working but I need to give differents colors and opacity to each layers (geojson representing polygons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's also possible to define all the styles w/i your javascript file using the [path.setStyle() method](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.0.1/l-path/).  Something like:

```
SupIncend.setStyle({
        fillColor: '<color>',
        color: '<color',
        weight: <number>
    });
```

Note that the style options are [leaflet path options](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.0.1/l-path/), which are not the same as the simple-style-spec options.

The simple-style-spec options *are* really useful, but it can be nice to keep your data and styles separate.  Also, using the `setStyle()` method makes it possible to dynamically style features, e.g. in response to a button click.  Something like:

```
button.on('click', function(){
    SupIncend.eachLayer(function(cell){
        var p = cell.feature.properties;

        // color
        if(p.field === <value1>){
            cell.setStyle({
                fillColor:<color1>
            });
        }else if(p.field === <value2>){
            cell.setStyle({
                fillColor:<color2>
            });
        }else{
            cell.setStyle({
                fillColor:<color3>
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as to add properties field to the Geojson with the [simple style specifications](https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec)

```
 "properties": {"fill": "#B10001","fill-opacity": 0.2,"stroke": "#B10001",
 "stroke-opacity": 1,"stroke-width": 2,"title": "Ãrea del Incendio"}
```